# display the filled form after clicking the submit button

Tags: html

I am making a form and I want when I click on the submit button it will display the filled form and display same as it display now with all the input filled
and it display in same format

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" required />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="number-label" for="number">Age<span class="clue">(optional)</span></label
        >
        <input
            type="number"
            name="age"
            id="number"
            min="10"
            max="99"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Age"
        />
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Which option best describes your current role?</p>
        <select id="dropdown" name="role" class="form-control" required>
            <option disabled selected value>Select current role</option>
            <option value="student">Student</option>
            <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>
            <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
            <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Any comments or suggestions?</p>
    <textarea id="comments" class="input-textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment here..."></textarea>
  </div><br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
        Submit
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is what you want. But before that try to express the question correctly

> ###### Use this js Code to clear the form data after submit

*This is just an example to make you understand so add some ids for the form tag and input and used the script same as given instead just change the id names*

- Add a class as Main-form
- and add a default option in select input. so that when submitted options become a default.
- Here we are clearing the value present in the inputs
- Same inputs id's are used for js code

```js
function clear(){
 let x = document.getElementById("survey-form").className;
 if(x == "main-form"){
   document.getElementById("Name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("age").value = "";
  document.getElementById("dropdown").value = "default";
  document.getElementById("comments").value = ""; 
 }else{
  document.getElementById("Name").value;
  document.getElementById("email").value;
  document.getElementById("age").value;
  document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  document.getElementById("comments").value; 
  }
  }
```

```html
    <form id="survey-form" class="main-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" required />
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="number-label" for="number">Age<span class="clue">(optional)</span></label
            >
            <input
                type="number"
                name="age"
                id="number"
                min="10"
                max="99"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Age"
            />
        </div><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Which option best describes your current role?</p>
            <select id="dropdown" name="role" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="default">Select current role</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
                <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>
                <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
                <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <p>Any comments or suggestions?</p>
        <textarea id="comments" class="input-textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment here..."></textarea>
      </div><br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="clear()" class="submit-button">
            Submit
            </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: from your code after clicking on submit its not showing any filled form. it clear the screen

Comment: Did you tried this in your pc or any online text editor

Comment: i tried on my pc it clear the form that i not want i want filled form/ output of the form all field are filled

Comment: Say Exactly what you want. Like do you want the do of form to your server